# Show that $t\mapsto\int_0^tf(s)\:{\rm d}s$ is absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, absolute-continuity

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be locally Lebesgue integrable and $$g(t):=\int_0^tf(s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$

Using the dominated convergence theorem, it is easy to show that $g$ is continuous, but how can we show that $g$ is absolutely continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about absolute continuity on the whole of $[0,\infty)$ (in the sense for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\sum |f(b_i)-f(a_i)| <\epsilon $ whenever $(a_i,b_i)$ are disjoint intervals with $\sum (b_i-a_i) <\delta$) then the result is false. Absolute continuity implies uniform continuity. If $f(s)=s$ then your hypothesis is satisfied but $g$ is not uniformly continuous.

What is true is $g$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,T]$ for any $T <\infty$.

[For a proof note that $f$ is integrable on $[0,T]$ and this implies there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\int_A |f|<\epsilon$ whenever $A$ is measurable with $\lambda (A) <\delta$. ($\lambda$=Lebesgue measure). Ref: Rudin's RCA].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've taken a look into Rudin. Does it hold that $g$ is differentiable Lebesgue almost everywhere with $g'=f$? He's claiming this only under the stronger assumption that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable (on the whole set $\mathbb R$), but I don't see why this assumption should be necessary.

Comment: Local integrability is enough for this.  @0xbadf00d

Comment: So, if we define $h:=e^{-g}$, we can immediately conclude that there is a Lebesgue null set $N\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $h$ is differentiable at $t$ with $h'(t)=-h(t)f(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb R\setminus N$. However, what I would like to conclude is that $$h(b)=h(a)-\int_a^bh(t)f(t)\:{\rm d}t\tag1$$ **for all** $b\ge a\ge0$. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, $g$ and $h$ are absolutely continuous on any bounded interval, so you can draw that conlcusion.  @0xbadf00d

Comment: So, aren't we immediately able to conclude that the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481340/47771) is positive?

Comment: Oh, and it which section of Rudin's theorem is the result you've mentioned? I only found Theorem 7.11. (You can find the international version of the book if you search, for example, for "Note also that Theorem 7 .. 10 leads to a correspondingly stronger form of" in google.)